# Android Bitmap decode error, not on all devices

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory, decode

i finished my App and started testing it on other devices. My own Device is a HTC One M7 and its working fine. Then i tested it on a Samsung Galaxy S4, the first 2 Layouts are shown but when i start the GameActivity it crashes. Same on an emulated Nexus 7. 
But on a ldpi Emulator it works fine.

This is the error i get on the Nexus 7.

```
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514): Process: com.example.test, PID: 1514
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:445)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:475)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at com.example.test.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:93)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at com.example.test.GameActivity.onResume(GameActivity.java:49)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-31 11:27:55.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone tell me why it is working on 2 Devices and failing on 2 others?

Comment: Because you are out of memory on two devices, due to the particular heap limit set on those devices, how you have used memory to date in your process, and the image that you are trying to load.

Comment: But my HTC One and the Galaxy S4 have the same technical specs, shouldn't ne the heap-size the same? I think i have to work on my Bitmap usage...

Comment: The heap limit is up to the manufacturer. Use `ActivityManager` to find out your heap limit. And, you may or may not have done the same things in your app up to the point of the error, meaning that the heap is not necessarily in the same state. Bear in mind that [the Dalvik garbage collector is not a compacting collector](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/16/art-garbage-collection.html), and so your heap will fragment, making it difficult to make large allocations over time.